# Запуск с параметрами

Tags: python

У меня есть скрипт, который принимает 2 аргумента при запуске.

Запустить его можно через консоль так:
bot.py login password

Как мне можно запустить этот скрипт не из консоли, а из кода на python. И чтобы при этом скрипт, в котором вызвали процесс, продолжал работу, а не останавливался. Через os.system этого не сделать. Может есть другие способы?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: пытался использовать, но не получается

Comment: def add(login,password):
    global bots
    bots += 1
    subprocess.Popen(['bot.pyw', '-c', login+':'+password])

Comment: Выдаёт такую ошибку - https://imgur.com/a/CGzaTFv

Comment: Потому что скрипт не является исполняемым файлом и из него невозможно создать процесс. Нужно запускать интерпретатор python и передавать ему скрипт.